# Calling child component function from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using "refs" to call a function(checkAndErase) in child component from parent, but cannot get it to work. Can anyone help me here please, since I m new to react. Thanx in advance
Throws error:
"Cannot read property checkAndEarse() of undefined"

Below is my parent render function:

```
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity disabled={initing} onPress={this.refs.child.checkAndErase()} style={styles.actionButton}>
        <Text style={[styles.actionButtonText, initing && styles.disabled]}>
        Eraser
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

  <Board puzzle={puzzle} ref={ref => {this.child = ref}} solve={this.solve} erasing={erasing} editing={editing}
  onInit={this.onInit.bind(this)} onErrorMove={this.onErrorMove} onFinish={this.onFinish}/>
```

Comment: Hey, Milan. I would back up and consider how you can accomplish what you need without calling a child component function directly. React is a view library, and its strength is in limiting the flow of information between components so you can have predictable and efficient rendering. A better design is probably to have a container component that performs changes to the board state, e.g. solve(), and then pass presentational information only through props.

Comment: I think you just need to change this:

`onPress={this.refs.child.checkAndErase()}`

to this:

`onPress={() => this.refs.child.checkAndErase()}`

Comment: Erik is right. Moving your state up to a "higher" component in the tree will allow you to pass data and functions from parent to child, which is the idiomatic way to do things in React.

BUT, to directly answer your question, try `onPress={() => this.child.checkAndErase()}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrow function syntax to late-bind to the child's method:

```
onPress={() => this.child.checkAndErase()}
```

Comment: It's stored via a callback ref and directly accessible at `this.child`. `this.refs.child` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `current` object of ref. It contains all the details (state, props, methods blah blah) of the child component in `react JS`. I am hoping same will be true for `react-native` as well.

So, imo it should be

```
onPress={() => this.child.current.checkAndErase()}
```

NOTE: You may need do add those traditional null checks. i.e. `this.child.current && this.child.current.checkAndErase()`

Cheers!!